# Is it possible to detect that current user is logged in with `signInWithCustomToken` method?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I would like to use `createCustomToken` and `signInWithCustomToken` methods to implement user impersonation. Is it possible somehow to tell that current user is logged in with `signInWithCustomToken` to detect that currently user impersonation is taking place?
I guess I can write something to the local storage after `signInWithCustomToken` succeeded but maybe there is better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When signing in with a custom token, the ID token will contain a claim specifying this. `tokenObject.firebase.sign_in_provider` will be equal `custom`.

When verifying server side, you can use the [`verifyIdToken`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#verify_id_tokens_using_the_firebase_admin_sdk) and inspect this.

Firebase Auth specifies APIs to get this client side:

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdTokenResult()
  .then((result) => {
    // Will output `custom`.
    console.log(result.claims.firebase.sign_in_provider);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way I found for this is to set custom developer claims property when calling `createCustomToken`. On client-side I can parse id token and extract developer claims.